# Stream a local parquet file to huggingface trainer with an Iterable Dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, parquet, huggingface-transformers

I would like to stream a large .parquet file that I have locally to train a classification model.
My script only seems to load the 1st mini batch: the number of epochs increases very quickly even though the file is very large, 1 epoch should last about ten hours. Here is the code I use:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import torch
import pandas as pd
import evaluate
from transformers import (AutoTokenizer, CamembertForSequenceClassification,
                          EarlyStoppingCallback, Trainer, TrainingArguments,
                          pipeline)
import numpy as np

class MyIterableDataset(torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):

    def __init__(self, parquet_file_path: str, tokenizer, label_encoder, batch_size: int = 8):
        self.parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(parquet_file_path)
        self.generator = self.parquet_file.iter_batches(batch_size=batch_size)
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.label_encoder = label_encoder

    def __iter__(self):
        """ """
        data = next(self.generator)
        encodings = self.tokenizer(data['text'].tolist(), truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=512)
        items = []
        for idx in range(len(data)):
            item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in encodings.items()}
            item["labels"] = torch.tensor(self.label_encoder.transform([str(data['target'][idx])]))
            items.append(item)
        return iter(items)
```

```
path_train_parquet = '...'
path_dev_parquet = '...'

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("camembert-base")

model = CamembertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("camembert-base", num_labels=4)
metric = evaluate.load("f1")

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels, average='macro')

train_dataset = MyIterableDataset(path_train_parquet, tokenizer, label_encoder, batch_size)
dev_dataset = MyIterableDataset(path_dev_parquet, tokenizer, label_encoder, batch_size)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=path_output_model,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    warmup_steps=10,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir=path_logging_dir_model,
    logging_steps=10,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    evaluation_strategy = 'steps',
    eval_steps=200,
    save_total_limit = 5,
    save_steps=200,
    report_to='none',
    max_steps=100000
            )

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=dev_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    callbacks = [EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3)]
                )
trainer.train()
trainer.save_model(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__iter__` method doesn't iterate over the entire dataset because it lacks a loop to repeatedly fetch the next batch of data and process it. Instead, it loads the first batch using `next(self.generator)`, processes it, and then *returns an iterator* containing the items from that batch. Since it only executes once, you get only the first batch in your dataset.

You could try something like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    while True:
        try:
            data = next(self.generator) #try and get the next bit of data
        except StopIteration:
            # End of the dataset, break
            break

        encodings = self.tokenizer(data['text'].tolist(), truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=512)
        items = []
        for idx in range(len(data)): #for index encode and yield
            item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in encodings.items()}
            item["labels"] = torch.tensor(self.label_encoder.transform([str(data['target'][idx])]))
            items.append(item)
        yield from items
```

This version should let the `__iter__` method keep fetching batches from `self.generator`, processing them, and yielding individual items from each batch until there are no more batches left in the .parquet file.

https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/python-iterators-generators-tutorial

https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-iterator-vs-generator/

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply, it works with this class. I made 2 mistakes: 
-I misunderstood the use of the __iter__ function, I thought there were several calls for each epoch whereas there is only one.
-The use of an IterableDataset now seems less relevant to me, I think it should be possible to use a classic Dataset.